# How C stores global struct variables? And weird behavior when converting to another pointer to struct type

Tags: c, struct

How does C store global struct variables?
Also, if I try to assign a smaller struct object to a pointer of a larger struct?
Basically this:

```
struct A{
int a;
};
struct B{
int b;
};

struct C{
struct A a;
struct B b;
};

struct A aa;
struct C * c = (struct C*) &aa;
```

What memory location does `c->b` gets to point to?

I tried a basic example and it seems, no matter in what order I declare/initialize two variables, the compiler is always coupling `s1` to `s3` in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
struct One{
    int a;
    int b;
} s2,s1,*sp1;
 
int e;
int ff;
 
struct Two{
    int c, d;
} q,r,t, s4,s3;
 
struct Three
{
    struct One one;
    struct Two two;
};
 
int main()
{
    e=1;
    sp1=&s1;
    sp1->a=1;
    s4.c=22;
    s3.c=10;
    struct Three * ll = (struct Three *) sp1;
    ll->two.c = 1000;
    printf("\n%d\t%d", s3.c, s4.c);
   return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on why it might be happening?
Link for running/output: https://www.ideone.com/YP4Y1e

**Edit:**
Thanks everyone, I understand this is bad coding practice. But I was more puzzled since in the full code example I gave, compiler was always putting `s1` and `s3` together in memory so my pointer `ll->two` had data from `s3`.
But it seems it is readonly. If I change value of `ll->two.c` the same is not reflected in `s3.c`. That lead me to believe that compiler might be copying the data to some other location in memory and `ll` might not be assigned a contiguous block of memory.

Is this behavior expected? You can read random block of memory with a bigger pointer type but cannot write to it? Or it is just undefined behavior as well?

Comment: `c->b` points to "random" memory because the cast `(struct C*) &aa;` violated the rules of C and invoked *undefined behavior*. You cannot "upcast" to a "bigger" type and expect something sensible to occur

Comment: Remove the "casting" and the compiler will tell you `struct C * c = &aa;` is invalid. By "casting" the address of `aa`, you have overruled the compiler's beneficial warning. You lose...

Comment: The sequence of variables in memory does not depend on the order of their definition. Some compilers may sort them on the hash values of their names, what might explain the effect you see. Anyway, this is a dead end.

Comment: @UnholySheep `(struct C*) &aa;` is fine, as per 6.7.2.1/15.

Comment: @Fe2O3 That's just because you can't direct assign a `struct A*` to `struct C*` since the types are not compatible. However, a `struct A*` may be "suitably converted" by means of a cast to `struct C*` and vice versa, since the first member of `struct C` is a `struct A`.

Comment: @Lundin The OP asks "What memory location does c->b point to?" and the answer is "the wilderness" because the programmer thought "I know better than the compiler what can be done." "Bad practices" are called "bad" for a reason.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the details... I have edited the question with another follow up question, if you could answer that please.

Answer (score 2):

Where variables are physically allocated in memory is beyond the scope of the C standard. Pretty much the only guarantees you have from the C standard are these:

- An arrays or a raw chunk of data allocated by malloc have the items allocated in adjacent order.
- Struct members are allocated in the specified order, with the first mentioned member on the lowest address. (Struct members may however not necessarily be allocated adjacently in relation to each other.)

Some systems may allocate variables in a certain order or allow you to allocate variables at absolute addresses, but that's all beyond the scope of the C standard and non-standard language extensions as well as linker scripts are needed for that.

---

`struct C * c = (struct C*) &aa;` happens to be a valid cast since the first member of a `struct C` is a `struct A`. Accessing `c->a` is well-defined because of this special first member rule, which also happens to be the one guaranteeing order of allocation of struct members:

ISO 9899:2018 6.2.1/15

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have
> addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object,
> suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in
> which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not
> at its beginning.

But beyond that, `c` doesn't actually point at a `struct C` so you can't access `c->b`, because it doesn't exist. Doing so is similar to an out of bounds access, meaning undefined behavior. I believe that 6.5.3.2 also applies: "If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined".

Your second example has the same problems.

Comment: There's no question that the pointer cast is valid.  It is sufficient that both the original and the target type are pointer-to-structure types, as the only caveat for the conversion itself is that UB occurs if the result is not correctly aligned for the target type.  All structure-pointer types have the same alignment requirement.  The types of the structure members are not relevant there.  Whether subsequently accessing `c->a` violates the strict aliasing rule is less clear.  It *does* violate the SAR (thus producing UB) if one interprets it to involve accessing `*c`.

Comment: If we say that `c->b` is invalid because `c` doesn't actually point to a `struct C`, as in fact you do, then that makes for a bit of a challenge in accepting `c->a` as valid.  But what other reason can we give for `c->b` being invalid?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Strict aliasing is compatible with the "first member" conversion rule. One exception from strict aliasing is "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members", where "aforementioned types" means a type compatible with the effective type of the object. However, the effective type of whatever happens to be stored at `c->b` it not a `struct B`.

Comment: That does not quite hold together for `c->a`.  If we say that accessing `aa` via that lvalue is ok because the lvalue has type `struct A` and that agrees with the referenced object's type, then we're not using the structure-member provision of the SAR, and we are implicitly claiming that we are *not* accessing `*c` (and to avoid an SAR violation we must indeed take the position that we are not accessing `*c`).  But how do we know that `c->a` references a `struct A`, or which one, if we acknowledge that `*c` is not, in fact, a `struct C`?  I submit that the `->` has UB here.

Comment: C17, 6.5.2.3/4: "A postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member ***of the object to which the first expression points*** [...]" (emphasis added).  I submit that this does not define behavior for the case where the pointer does not, in fact, point to an object of the referenced type.  *That's* the reason for `c->b` having UB, and I see no reason why it would not also apply to `c->a`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok yeah the lvalue access is of type `struct A` so the aliasing exception doesn't apply. But that also means that it isn't a strict aliasing violation since `struct A` is the correct type. This all isn't really covered well by the standard. And if you keeping reading 6.5.2.3 you also have the oddball "common initial sequence" rule, which applies to unions only, but allows an initial part of a struct to be "inspected".

Comment: Correct, it's not a strict-aliasing violation if, for the sake of argument, we interpret the situation as not involving an access to `*c`.  But that doesn't make the behavior of `c->a` defined (by the spec) any more than the behavior of `c->b` is.  The undefined behavior of `c->a` has a good chance of manifesting as equivalent to `aa.a`, but it is not guaranteed to do so.  It is *not* well-defined.

Comment: In the full code that I have given at the end, the compiler seems to be arranging s1 and s3 together in memory. So `ll->two` points to s3. But it seems to be only readonly. Writing to it doesn't change value in s3? Could there be a reason for it or is it just "undefined behavior"?

Comment: @lucifer Undefined behavior means that the compiler might generate wrong or unexpected machine code. For example it is allow to deduct that nothing in your code seems to change s3 so therefore it can optimize the code to use the previous value  when that variable is used, even if you update the physical memory location.